# BackgroundAudioPlayer with playlist

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am playing around with the background audio player, creating a music player.

How am i suppose to communicate between my app and the music player? I would like my app to be able play a list of songs, that is on the SD card of the phone. I know i can set the Track property, and play that sound, but when the player is playing and the app is closed will i not be able to set the next song on.

I have read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx but in this example do they hard code the song list into to Background Player.

How can i load a list of songs into the Background Player while the app is running?

Answer (score 0):

What you do is save the list where a background audio player agent can access it. The agent then takes care of managing the list and playing the next track when one finishes.